# Сортировка по полю, разбитому на несколько значений

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с некоторыми записями:

```
id || params
----------------------------------
01 || 120__08.06.2019,10.07.2019,0
02 || 121__09.02.2019,,1
03 || 122__14.05.2019,20.06.2019,0
04 || 123__,,
05 || 124__21.06.2019,,1
```

**params** на примере #1 расшифровывается как:

```
1) 120 - внутренний порядковый номер (не нужен)
2) 08.02.2019 - дата начала фактуры (может быть пустой)
3) 10.03.2019 - дата конца фактуры (может быть пустой)
4) 0 - если ноль, то имеется дата конца, если 1 - фактура бессрочная и даты нет
```

нужно получить все записи, отсортированные по условиям:

1. сначала: если даты начала и даты конца нет
2. затем: DESC по дате конца, если (4) параметр равен 1, то считаем дату конца максимальной

Т.е. итоговый результат ожидается:
Сегодня 27.05.2019

```
id || params
----------------------------------
04 || 123__,,
03 || 122__14.05.2019,20.06.2019,0
01 || 120__08.06.2019,10.07.2019,0
02 || 121__09.02.2019,,1
05 || 124__21.06.2019,,1
```

Структуру таблицы изменять, к сожалению, запрещено. Заранее спасибо за решение или помощь.

Comment: Вы отдаете отчет, что быстро оно работать не будет? И даже наоборот - оно будет работать ОЧЕНЬ медленно?

Comment: Да, понимаю, но менять структуру таблицы пока тоже нет возможности :(

Comment: Ищите нужные маркеры в строке с помощью `LOCATE()`, выкусывайте нужную подстроку между ними с помощью `SUBSTR()`, и сортируйте добавляя условия если надо. Например, `ORDER BY IF(подстрока = условие, 0, 1)` поднимет выше строки с подходящим условием.

Comment: `Структуру таблицы изменять, к сожалению, запрещено.` только таблицы? а базы? можно добавить рядом новую таблицу(ы) с нормализованными значениями.

Comment: затем: DESC по дате конца, если (4) параметр равен 1, то считаем дату конца максимальной` может, все таки, ASC? По возрастанию

Comment: И версия MySQL какая?

Comment: Таблица заполняется отдельно от нас и нет привилегий на изменения, но по совету Lexx918 решено синхронизировать с нашей таблицей уже с нормальными полями

Comment: Сделайте представление, в нём выполните деление на 4 отдельных поля. Его используйте в качестве источника данных запроса. И формат даты для MySQL - хреновенький, парсить надо.

Comment: @Akina а какая разница где парсить строку? В самом запросе или в представлении?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Серверу в общем-то всё равно. А вот тексты запросов получатся попроще.

Answer (score 4):

> затем: **DESC** по дате конца, если (4) параметр равен 1, то считаем дату конца максимальной

Если в этой фразе `DESC` опечатка и подразумевалась сортировка по возрастанию, то вот решение для MySQL 8.0

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  data
ORDER BY
  params RLIKE '^[0-9]+__,*$' DESC,
  params RLIKE ',1$',
  STR_TO_DATE(
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(params, '[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4},0$') AS CHAR),
    '%d.%m.%Y,0'
  )
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kqs5TQLyhtHZNsTwCJDgsU/0)

А вот для MySQL 5.7, у которого нет функции `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  data
ORDER BY
  params RLIKE '^[0-9]+__,*$' DESC,
  params RLIKE ',1$',
  STR_TO_DATE(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(params, ',', 2),
      ',',
      -1
    ),
    '%d.%m.%Y,0'
  )
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hnQY216iFCLELQt8b1FigE/1)

Comment: Круто! Спасибо :)

Comment: @mico если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то отметьте его как верный

Comment: по совету Lexx918 сделал еще одну таблицу с полями и синхронизирую даты с таблицей params. А ваше решение не проверял, скорее просто восхитился)